# Python Selenium and Chromedriver CentOS8

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, centos8

I have a python script which use selenium and chromedriver.
It runs on my CentOS8 VPS perfectly for 3 days without any problem.

But since this morning, the script launched, wait almost 80 secondes and display this :

```
[12/Jan/2021 23:04:51] ERROR - Failed : Message: chrome not reachable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 55, in <module>
    driver = launch()
  File "script.py", line 37, in launch
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

No modification have been made, why does it fail now ?
I don't have any screen on my VPS so I can't see more information.

Here is some info :

**yum info on chromedriver :**

```
Nom          : chromedriver
Version      : 87.0.4280.88
Publication  : 1.el8
Architecture : x86_64
Taille       : 27 M
Source       : chromium-87.0.4280.88-1.el8.src.rpm
Dépôt        : @System
Depuis le dé : epel
```

**google-chrome --version :**

```
Google Chrome 87.0.4280.141
```

**Begin of the script :**

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from logger import logger as l
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import time
import sys
import subprocess

load_dotenv(verbose=True)
dotenv_path = '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

def launch():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
    l.info('Started Chrome')
    return browser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved but don't understand how.
I just restart my VPS (reboot), and ... it works again.
Weird

EDIT : Find why !
I just made a mistake at the end of my script :
b.close();
But "b" don't exist, my driver variable name is "driver".

The exception was catched and not displayed, so I don't saw anything.
But today, I launch a "top" command, and see all "chrome" process running in background.

Probably after several days, memory was full, and Chrome can't launch.
The error was not clear but anyway, it was my fault.

Answer (score -1):

### *Thumb rule*

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

---

### Solution

Remove the following `chrome_options`:

- `--no-sandbox`

and execute your code as a *non root* user.

---

### Outro

Here is the link to the [**Sandbox**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md) story.

Comment: Thx, but not working. I try to user the default "centos" user on the VPS, which is part of group root, and comment the "no-sandbox" line in script, but same result, nothing changed...

Comment: @user2178964 try to avoid group `root`

Comment: I use : usermod -g users centos , to make my CentOS user part of users group and not "root" group. But it doesn't change anything, the problem is clearly elsewhere...